# Trying to Write For-While Loop, not working

Tags: python, list, numbers, append

This is my first question, so I am sorry if it needs retitling or moving to another section.

I am trying to write a loop that will append numbers 1-4 to every string in list1 and put those new strings in list2. Here is what I'm doing so far:

```
number = 0
list1 = ["a","b","c"]
list2=[]
for item in list1:
    while number < 5:
        list2.append(str(item)+str(number))
        number = number + 1
```

I am lost on what to do next. Any help would be appreciated.

P.S. Right now, if i do 
    print list2 
it outputs 
    ['a0', 'a1', 'a2', 'a3', 'a4']. What I want to happen is

```
print list2

['a1', 'a2', 'a3', 'a4', 'b1', 'b2', 'b3', 'b4', 'c1', 'c2', 'c3', 'c4']
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you have initialized `number` outside the `for` loop.  As such, even though the `for` is executed for all items in `list1`, the `while` isn't executed for subsequent items as the condition is false.

```
list1 = ["a","b","c"]
list2=[]
for item in list1:
    number = 1       # You need to reset number within the loop, not outside!
    while number < 5:
        list2.append(str(item)+str(number))
        number = number + 1
print list2
```

Produces:

```
['a1', 'a2', 'a3', 'a4', 'b1', 'b2', 'b3', 'b4', 'c1', 'c2', 'c3', 'c4']
```

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative to other answers, you can alternatively use [list comprehension](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) to achieve the results you are looking for:

```
list1  = ['a','b', 'c']
number = 5
list2  = [ '%s%s' % (item, i+1) for item in list for i in range(0,number) ]
print list2
```

Produces

```
['a1', 'a2', 'a3', 'a4', 'a5', 'b1', 'b2', 'b3', 'b4', 'b5', 'c1', 'c2', 'c3', 'c4', 'c5']
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
number = 5
list1 = ["a","b","c"]
list2=[]
for item in list1:
    for i in range(1,number ):
        list2.append(str(item)+str(i))

print list2
```

Output:

```
['a1', 'a2', 'a3', 'a4', 'b1', 'b2', 'b3', 'b4', 'c1', 'c2', 'c3', 'c4']
```

The code you shared, requires the following edit:

```
list1 = ["a","b","c"]
list2=[]
for item in list1:
    number = 1    
    while number < 5:
        list2.append(str(item)+str(number))
        number = number + 1

print list2
```